# Issues with iOS simulator 4.3 in xCode 4.3.2

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I have just upgraded my xCode to 4.3.2. After this I can't find iOS simulator 4.3 in drop-down menu near run button - only 5.1. On previous version of xCode iOS there was simulator 4.3.

In order to install simulator 4.3 I tried to download it from xCode preferences, but I faced with the following warming alert:

```
The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a sever that is pretending to be "daw2.apple.com" which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

It seems that I have problems with certificates, but I have no idea with which one?

Could anybody help me?

Comment: Just go to Launchpad -> Utilities -> Keychain Access. Then there check for certificates for all keychains(e.g. Login, System). Also go to Devices tab from Organizer window & check certificates. Check if you could find any clue to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Xcode->Preferences->Downloads->iOS 4.3 Simulator and install it.